# AWS Extend custom metrics retention period

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have custom metrics, which are preserved for two weeks,

However i want to extend this period.

I googled around and found the retention period was already extended,

https://aws.amazon.com/jp/blogs/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-update-extended-metrics-retention-user-interface-update/

However still my custom metrics data is preservced only two weeks.

Is there any global setting for this?

Comment: are you talking about the One minute data?

Comment: Not only 1 min data but also 5min 15min 1hour etc..